# Javascript Show/Hide DIV on click/toggle

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

I list a lot of users on my page and I use a php function to pass the user's id and return a div pop up that displays their online status, avatar, stats etc. The problem is that the code is currently set to show the layer onmouseover and hide the layer onmouseout. I would like the code to be onclick show, and second click (either toggle on the same link or click anywhere else on the page) hide the layer but I'm not sure how to accomplish that.

The current code I'm using I got from Dynamic Drive. (sorry my tab key won't work in this text box, not sure how to fix that. feel free to edit)

**SKIP TO BOTTOM**

Original Method:

**Javascript part**

```
<div id="dhtmltooltip"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

/***********************************************
* Cool DHTML tooltip script- Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
***********************************************/

var offsetxpoint=-60 //Customize x offset of tooltip
var offsetypoint=20 //Customize y offset of tooltip
var ie=document.all
var ns6=document.getElementById && !document.all
var enabletip=false
if (ie||ns6)
var tipobj=document.all? document.all["dhtmltooltip"] : document.getElementById? document.getElementById("dhtmltooltip") : ""

function ietruebody(){
    return (document.compatMode && document.compatMode!="BackCompat")? document.documentElement : document.body
}

function ddrivetip(thetext, thecolor, thewidth){
    if (ns6||ie){
        if (typeof thewidth!="undefined") tipobj.style.width=thewidth+"px"
        if (typeof thecolor!="undefined" && thecolor!="") tipobj.style.backgroundColor=thecolor
        tipobj.innerHTML=thetext
        enabletip=true
        return false
    }
}

function positiontip(e){
    if (enabletip){
        var curX=(ns6)?e.pageX : event.clientX+ietruebody().scrollLeft;
        var curY=(ns6)?e.pageY : event.clientY+ietruebody().scrollTop;
        //Find out how close the mouse is to the corner of the window
        var rightedge=ie&&!window.opera? ietruebody().clientWidth-event.clientX-offsetxpoint : window.innerWidth-e.clientX-offsetxpoint-20
        var bottomedge=ie&&!window.opera? ietruebody().clientHeight-event.clientY-offsetypoint : window.innerHeight-e.clientY-offsetypoint-20

        var leftedge=(offsetxpoint<0)? offsetxpoint*(-1) : -1000

        //if the horizontal distance isn't enough to accomodate the width of the context menu
        if (rightedge<tipobj.offsetWidth)
        //move the horizontal position of the menu to the left by it's width
        tipobj.style.left=ie? ietruebody().scrollLeft+event.clientX-tipobj.offsetWidth+"px" : window.pageXOffset+e.clientX-tipobj.offsetWidth+"px"
        else if (curX<leftedge)
        tipobj.style.left="5px"
        else
        //position the horizontal position of the menu where the mouse is positioned
        tipobj.style.left=curX+offsetxpoint+"px"

        //same concept with the vertical position
        if (bottomedge<tipobj.offsetHeight)
        tipobj.style.top=ie? ietruebody().scrollTop+event.clientY-tipobj.offsetHeight-offsetypoint+"px" : window.pageYOffset+e.clientY-tipobj.offsetHeight-offsetypoint+"px"
        else
        tipobj.style.top=curY+offsetypoint+"px"
        tipobj.style.visibility="visible"
    }
}

function hideddrivetip(){
    if (ns6||ie){
        enabletip=false
        tipobj.style.visibility="hidden"
        tipobj.style.left="-1000px"
        tipobj.style.backgroundColor=''
        tipobj.style.width=''
    }
}

document.onmousemove=positiontip

</script>
```

**PHP part**

```
$username = "<a onMouseover=\"ddrivetip('<Center><font class=f2>$username</font><BR>$avatarl</center>
<table align=center><Tr><Td><b>Points:</b> <font class=alttext>$user_points</font>
<BR><B>Posts:</b> <font class=alttext>$user_posts</font><BR>$user_status</td></tr></table>
<BR><img src=$icons/add-user.png height=12> <a href=$cs_url/friends/add/$user>Send Friend Request</a>
<BR><img src=$icons/user_message2.png height=12> <a href=$cs_url/messages/compose/$user>Send Message</a>
<BR><img src=$icons/user_im2.png height=12> Instant Message')\"
onMouseout=\"hideddrivetip()\">$username</a>";
```

My primary reason for wanting the toggle/blur as opposed to mouseout is so that users have the chance to actually click the links inside of the div layer.

The reason why I am trying to stick to this script as opposed to other ones out there I've found is because it doesn't rely on unique ids or alot of css styles. With other scripts, when I click on one username, they all of the hidden divs on the page pop up, or at least all of them for that user. This seemed to be the best for showing just one at a time.

**I decided to scrap the method above. I have a script that I also got elsewhere that I use to toggle a twitter-like login in. I was wondering how I could use it to toggle the user information layer.**

Second Method:

**Javascript**

```
$(".users").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $("fieldset#users_menu").toggle();
     $(".users").toggleClass("menu-open");
});

$("fieldset#users_menu").mouseup(function() {
         return false
});
 $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
     if($(e.target).parent("a.users").length==0) {
         $(".users").removeClass("menu-open");
         $("fieldset#users_menu").hide();
     }
});
```

**PHP part**

```
<div id='container' class='users_container'>
    <div id='usersnav' class='usersnav'> <a href='<?php echo $cs_url; ?>/users/all' class='users'><span>Fans</span></a> </div>
        <fieldset id='users_menu'>
        content
        </fieldset>
</div>
```

The problem with this method as I mentioned before is that when I click on the username link, ALL of the layers for ALL of the users display on the page appear. How can I make it so that only the child layer of the parent link is displayed? Also, is there a way to toggle the layer hidden when anywhere else on the page is clicked?

Comment: your code is a mess. I hope you are new to coding, if not, that bad habit won't easily go away. Saving file-size is not an argument since there are 999+ free online code compressors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being the best solution though there is still one thing I wish was different about it.

This is built upon Dan's response. The reason why it wasn't working before Dan was because the user information was inside  tags, I switcher username to span and the content display. The problem after that was when I clicked on one username the layer would popup but it would remain until I clicked on the same link again. So multiple layers would sometimes be on at once.

The following closes the layer when a user clicks on the layer, outside the layer or on the original link. The one little snag is that when clicking on the original link to close the layer you must click twice.

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".username").click(function () {
         $(this).children().toggle();

        $('.tooltip_container').hover(function(){ 
            mouse_is_inside=true; 
        }, function(){ 
            mouse_is_inside=false; 
        });

        $(".username").click(function () {
             $(this).children().toggle();
        }); 

    }); 

    $("body").mouseup(function(){ 
        if(! mouse_is_inside) $('.tooltip_container').hide();
    });

});
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<span class='username'>$username
    <div class='tooltip_container'>
        <div class='tooltip'>
        Content goes here
        </div>
     </div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your old code I assume you had something like:

```
elem.onmouseover = showCard;
elem.onmouseout = hideCard;
```

Well, from there you just need to do something along the lines of:

```
elem.isShown = false;
elem.onclick = function() {
    if( elem.isShown) hideCard();
    else showCard();
    elem.isShown = !elem.isShown;
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything like that